# Boot Ubuntu 18.04 from SSD

Tags: boot

Good day,

Using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Optiplex 1710 with 500Gb HD and 250 Gb SSD.

I cloned my original installed Ubuntu HD (now : sdb) to an SSD (now : sda).
When the SSD is the only option (HD disconnected) it correctly boots from the SSD.

When the original HD is also connected it boots from the original HD.

I changed with grub-optimizer the boot sequence to boot from sda. wrote it to MBR on hda and hdb.

When booting with both drives, it boots from sdb = HD.
I tried to many options / changed a lot but i can not get a boot from the SSD.

Boot options when starting shows option to boot from hda.

Would appriciate help , any tips ?

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Your BIOS looks at the disk controllers and the disk drives, one at a time, starting at 0, and checks each partition on each disk for the first one with the "BOOT" flag, and boots from that one.

Comment: You cannot keep a cloned drive plugged in when you reboot. You have duplicate UUIDs which are not allowed and system may boot one or the other depending on which partition is seen first. Then you get installs out of sync and may have bigger issues. You can change UUIDs or every partition and fstab entries and maybe some other places if you want to keep it bootable. Generally clone is not the best backup procedure. exclude snaps list of UUIDs
`lsblk -af |grep -sv loop`

Comment: thank you for your answers. UUIDS where different. Also i used Gparted to set the SSD to " Boot" . I noticed the superblock where damaged. Going for a new install of the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the "Disk Identifier"  from `fdisk -l`  were different.
That is not the UUID !

List the UUID with `lsbik` and use that identifier.

I changed the entry in `/etc/fstab` and the Grub entry to the correct disk UUID and now it works.

Thanks for the hints.